# Change Border Thickness on Mouse Over UWP

Tags: mvvm, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, template10

I am designing menu and I have list of items in VariableSizedWrapGrid as shown in figure.
[image]
I want to change border thickness of Current active element on MouseOver also I want to change foreground color of title 'Business'.
How should I achieve this in UWP using MVVM?

Way I know is:

1. Use Interaction and call ViewModel command on MoseOver.
2. Command will set BorderWidth property of VIewModel
3. BorderWidth property would bind to BorderThickness property of control

   BorderThickness="{Binding BorderWidth}"

This will work great with one VariableSizedWrapGrid's item. But I have 3 items as shown above. Do I need to create 3 commands with 3 ViewModel Properties which will bind border thickness to respective item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change SelectedBackground in ListViewItemPresenter inside a GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705396/how-to-change-selectedbackground-in-listviewitempresenter-inside-a-gridview)

Comment: This is a UI concern, so your VM shouldn't be involved in it whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless if you have a real reason to set the `BorderWidth` from inside your viewmodel (e.g. calculated width depending on other properties of your viewmodel/model, you can simply edit the default `GridViewItem` style and use the `VisualStateManager` to handle the `PointerOver` event.

You can find the default styles on your disk, with a file per SDK version.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10586.0\Generic\generic.xaml

Or you can also find them on MSDN, like the one for [GridViewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You can also [edit the existing style in Blend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170032.aspx).

You'll end with a custom style with a name (x:Key) that you can use on your `VariableSizedGrid`'s `GridViewItem`. The part in the style that you have to edit is in the `PointerOver` visual state:

```
  <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
    <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                       Duration="0"
                       To="1"/>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
    </Storyboard>
  </VisualState>
```

As you can see, the state already changes the `Opacity` and `Stroke`, just add another `DoubleAnimation` for the `BorderThickness` properties. Other states will use the default.

Comment: Thanks proper use of template editable controls with ViewStateManager and blend made my day.